# Adding an value to multidimensional array in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I need to add values in an multidimensional array whitin an while loop. But I don't know how.

```
public Array getDailyAvgRatingByCompanyId(int companyId, int periodStart = 0, int periodEnd = 0)
        {
            int[,] arr = { { }, { } };

            string queryString = "SELECT num_ratings_day, rating_gem, daymonthyear FROM company_rating_daily_avg WHERE company_id = " + companyId + " ORDER BY daymonthyear ASC";
            SqlDataReader myDataReader = Database.sqlDataReader(queryString);

            if (myDataReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (myDataReader.Read())
                {
                    //Something like arr[0].Push(myDataReader['num_ratings_day']
                }
            }

            return arr;
        }
```

Comment: You might want to consider using parameterised SQL instead of what you have, to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Just a thought - To simplify this you could return say a List<DailyAvgRating> or ArrayList where DailyAvgRating is a class/struct/model that contains CompanyId, and your SQL columns (e.g. Num_Rating_Day, Rating_Gem, DayMonthYear) result.

Comment: @Graham Clark: I get what you're saying and on the whole parametrised queries are safer, but since Boyd is only inputting numbers, there is no SQL injection vector here.

Comment: what do the indices of your array represent, boyd? is it `arr[row, col]`?

Comment: @Matt it must be filled with data to be handled by an graph class. So it must contain values for the x and y. Like { {x1, x2, x3}, {y1, y2, y3} }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes that you want all the columns in the query put into the array, and that all the columns return ints.

```
public Array getDailyAvgRatingByCompanyId(int companyId, int periodStart = 0, int periodEnd = 0)
{
    List<int[]> rowList = new List<int[]>();

    string queryString = "SELECT num_ratings_day, rating_gem, daymonthyear FROM company_rating_daily_avg WHERE company_id = " + companyId + " ORDER BY daymonthyear ASC";
    SqlDataReader myDataReader = Database.sqlDataReader(queryString);

    if (myDataReader.HasRows)
    {
        while (myDataReader.Read())
        {
            int[] values = new int[3];
            values[0] = myDataReader['num_ratings_day'];
            values[1] = myDataReader['rating_gem'];
            values[2] = myDataReader['daymonthyear'];
            rowList.add(values);
        }
    }

    int[,] arr = new int[rowList.Count, 3];

    for(int i = 0; i < rowList.Count; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            arr[i,j] = rowList[i][j];
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a data type other than Array for this.

Try using a List of arrays:

```
var list = new List<int[]>();

if (myDataReader.HasRows)
{
    while (myDataReader.Read())
    {
        var int1 = ??; // Get data 1
        var int2 = ??; // Get data 2

        list.Add(new[] { int1, int2 });
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that I don't have a choice.. I need to fill the array excactly this way because that's how the data is handled by another part of the system.

Comment: This works, except mines are string instead of int. How can I sort the list by string2 (int2) in your case?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DataTable by creating a SqlDataAdapter (with SELECT Statement), and than DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable).
So you retrieve a DataTable with all values returned by sql statement